# Application Insights Duration stopped working after TraceListener added

Tags: c#, azure, asp.net-web-api, azure-application-insights

I have a WebAPI project which is deployed to azure.  Based on [this Azure Friday](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/resources/videos/instrumenting-your-web-api-using-application-insights-with-victor-mushkatin/)...

I've added

```
Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Tracing 5.2.2
```

to my webapi project (Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi* are all 5.2.2).

Then, I added

```
ApplicationInsights.Web 2.2
```

to the web api project.

At this point, when I run the application, I'm only seeing dependency information since my app does not manually send any telemetry.  I am not getting any server information at this point.

Then I added

```
ApplicationInsights.TraceListener 2.2
```

At this point, I'm getting server information, but all my dependency information is gone.

I would imagine that I should be able to get both sets of information, any idea what could be wrong?

Comment: Where are you viewing the telemetry data? When you make Web API calls are you not seeing Request data alongwith dependency information? ApplicationInsights.Web is the only package needed to configure telemetry in a WebAPI (Note that it installs about 5-6 dependent packages including ApplicationInsights.Core). The only other step is to ensure your instrumentation key is present. You can try checking 'Diagnostic Events' window in VS to see if telemetry is being sent correctly to Application Insights while debugging the Web API.